User flow of booking wizard
I am designing a booking wizard for external users to book a meeting room with a shared office provider.
The wizard has 5 steps:
Step 1: choose your meeting room
Step 2: Add options such as name of meeting, description and add guests (with the possibility to add paying parking spots per guest)
Step 3: Add Extras such as catering, office supplies but also parking spots
Step 4: Confirm (which is a summary)
Step 5: Pay
Adding step 2 seems logical but is optional (they can manage that after payment as well) and adds to the complexity because what a user adds here as parking spot should be automatically updated in step 3 too, and the other way around.
I added this step because in a logical flow I think a user might want to name a meeting and invite guests in the same flow as booking a meeting room. But since it’s optional and it adds to the complexity (both for the developer as most likely for the user) I am not sure if it’s not best to remove it and let users do it after payment.

What is the question?

I didn't exactly formulate a question did I? I was meaning to ask the community what they thought about the case, whether it would be best to add step 2 or not.

Where does the booking happen? On the computer, mobile, or even within the room? (this question could have an impact depending on the device) maybe the flow you're proposing is not well-defined. When you schedule a meeting, you first select the time, then the people attending, and finally, the place.
If the wizard identifies people who do not belong to your organization, you could include add-ons like catering and parking.

I just want to share my though,
If it is optional, it's better to remove it and reduce the fields/time to do the booking process.
One thing I should consider is about the guests, because it will impact the payment so it's better that the user understand two things:

First, be aware to posiblity about adding guests
Second, by doing this action, the total price will be incremented (we need to show how much it will increment for each guest)

Maybe this guests option can be grouped in the extras step.
Once the users complete the wizard process, they could be redirected to a screen with the options of customize the booking with the name and the description, but it should be considered as optional as well, probably the name can be generated automatically with the edit option...
Kind regards!

Thank you all! I decided the best thing to do was to indeed remove that optional step and let the booker invite guests afterwards. It was getting too lengthy, seemed not all people wanted to invite guests at the wizard stage and it added too much complexity (which impacts the user too). The experience feels a bit disconnected this way but after consideration, it is best. I just added a notification during the wizard that inviting guests can be done afterwards.
